# How can map side join perform worse than the regular one (HIVE)

Tags: hive, hiveql, amazon-emr

I have performance issues with the following query:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE output PARTITION(`date`)
SELECT DISTINCT
  i1.type,
  i1.id1,
  i1.id2,
  i1.id3,
  i1.id4,
  i1.input_date AS `date`
FROM input1 AS i1 INNER JOIN input2 AS i2 ON i1.token = i2.token
WHERE i1.city IN ('london', 'paris') AND i2.p_id != '1234'
  AND COALESCE(i1.id1, i1.id2, i1.id3, i1.id4) IS NOT NULL;
```

Where the table **input1** consists of ten files ~40mb each (ORC, compressed), and the table **input2** consists of 1 txt file (~50kb). There is a huge difference in execution time depending on the value of *hive.auto.convert.join* parameter (when auto convert set to false the query runs 20x times faster), but I can't find a reason why is this the case.

Btw I'm running hive on only one node, in both cases cluster has a lot of unused ram, hive version is 2.3.5

Comment: Are data type of these fields are same -i1.id1, i1.id2, i1.id3, i1.id4? The expressions after COALESCE should all have the same type otherwise hive will try to convert them to check if its null.

Comment: @KoushikRoy all these fields are strings